# Text Qualifier syntax in PDW dwloader

Tags: sql, sql-server, pdw-file-browser

I am using dwloader utility to load data into PDW. My dwloader syntax is given below:

```
    dwloader.exe  -M reload -b 200000 -i \d\Development\Source\FACT.TXT -T Test_DB.dbo.FACT_LOAD -R \d\Development\Bad\FACT_LOAD.bad -t "," -fh 1 -r \r\n -D "yyyy-MM-dd" -E -S 10.1.1.19 -U Devl_User -P Password1> "\d\Development\Log\FACT_LOAD.log"

Pause
```

I got the data loaded into the table. But all the `varchar` columns have data within double `'quotes'`. My text file is commma delimited. Any idea on how to include the text qualifier in the above syntax?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured the answer myself. Including " -s 0x22" in the command above will escape the double quotes.